# Connecting two Kinects simultaneously using Fuerte?

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, openni-kinect, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Fuerte on Linux, and right now I can run one Kinect using roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, and use rviz to see both the depth and RGB cameras.

How can I get a second Kinect to work simultaneously? I tried attaching a second Kinect to a different USB bus, and lsusb recognizes both, but rviz still only sees the first Kinect when using Pointcloud2.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36444/connecting-two-kinects-simultaneously-using-fuerte?/) by [molgamic](https://answers.ros.org/users/2606/molgamic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to provide some parameters to the second call to `roslaunch`, so that it picks up the correct device, and publishes the second point cloud on a different topic.

Also, you'll need to put each Kinect on a different USB bus; a Kinect saturates the bus it's on.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0